# Why does this `join` method call with no arguments succeed?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

This Groovy script looks simple enough:

```groovy
def a = [].join()
println a
```

I would expect it to throw `MissingMethodException` because `join` method requires a parameter, if I'm looking at [the right one](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String)), but it works [just fine](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eNpLSU1TSFSwVYiO1cvKz8zT0OQqKMrMK8nJU0jkAgB9Lwix).
And [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L5960) is the source code for that method, so the parameter is definitely not optional.
You know where it fails the way I expect it to? In Jenkins, of course.

So, why does it work? Is there some Groovy convention I don't know about? Or does it actually call a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are providing the parameter, but it is null. You are in the end calling this method in DefaultGroovyMethods class:

```
public static String join(Iterator<?> self, String separator) {
        if (separator == null) {
            separator = "";
        }
...
```

While default groovy methods are injected into all Groovy objects (you can find this information [here](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/) among comments) I assume first parameter is always populated by the fact of injecting it to iterable while the second as you can see is set to be empty string when it is null. Thus `[].join()` in my opinion passes empty list and null to the `join` method and it effectively means setting empty string as separator.

**EDIT:**
Yes, you are right we could do more digging on the subject. For sure Groovy assumes null was passed when function requiring 1 parameter (but not primitive type) is called without parameters:

```
def f1(String a){
    println a
}

f1() // prints word "null"
```

[Here](https://objectpartners.com/2015/09/02/groovy-gotcha-passing-zero-arguments-to-a-method-that-expects-one/) is some info from somebody who spotted it 8 years ago as well.
I am sure this is your missing puzzle - giving no parameters causes Groovy to pass null when parameter is not of primitive type. I do not know how mechanism of injecting default groovy methods makes possible for `join` method to accept `Iterable` but `String` parameter behaviour should be clear now. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, your reply has some useful pointers, but doesn't really answer the question why method call with only one parameter (`self`) resolves to a method with two parameters in its signature, and none of those parameters are optional. Will it work the same way for other methods with non-optional parameters, like `[1,2,3].count()`? Easy to find that it won't. But thank you for engaging!

Comment: Edited the answer with more info.